# How to set batchSize in change stream watch api (mongo-go-driver)?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I am passing batchSize using `changestreamopt.BatchSize`.
But this not working this error occurred: `BSON field '$changeStream.batchSize' is an unknown field`

Sample API call

```
// coll is  *mongo.Collection
// ctx is context
cur, err := coll.Watch(ctx, nil, changestreamopt.BatchSize(1000))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the current `mongo-go-driver` (v0.0.16) where the `batchSize` option is passed into the `$changestream` pipeline stage instead to the cursor.

The code [change_stream.go#L66-L73](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/v0.0.15/mongo/change_stream.go#L66-L73) seems to only use `maxAwaitTime` to the cursor.

I've opened a ticket [GODRIVER-591](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/GODRIVER-591) with the MongoDB Go driver team.